# Android back button does not work

Tags: java, android, android-activity, cocos2d-x

I am using cocos2dx to make a small game and in the activity of my game i give the following functions to handle back button.

```
@Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
 {
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy()
 {
     android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
     super.onDestroy();
 }
```

On pressing back button i get the following warning in my logcat

> Can't open keycharmap file
>
> Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/qtouch-touchscreen.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65538.devname='qtouch-touchscreen'

The call doesn't reach onKeyDown or onDestroy functions.

Please tell me why this warning is caused and why i cannot handle the android back button.

The functions work fine on my java android project but not in my cocos2d-x project

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is been handled here in the file `Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView.java`

change it to below, where `myActivity` is the cocos2dActicity

```
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(myActivity)
                    .setTitle("EXIT?")
                    .setMessage("Do you really want to exit?")
                    .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ((Cocos2dxActivity)myActivity).finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    }).create();
                    ad.show();
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
```

Comment: It doesn't exit, when I run it again the continues from where it was.

Comment: How exactly do you get access to the activity here?

Comment: @BrandonRomano please pass the main acticyty as an arguments when the `Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView` instance is been constructed in the main activity. you probably need a variable inside `Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView.java` to store it, in my case is myActivity.

Answer (score 2):

To handle back button pressing you need to redefine `onBackPressed()` method of your activity,  not this two methods.

Comment: I tried this too but call is not reaching 'onBackPressed()' method either.

Comment: It seems cocos caprute back pressing. Check this message, maybe this is what you are looking for http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/5041?r=5059#message-5059

Comment: But this will help only if i am inheriting CCLayer which i am not. Is there any other way to solve this crisis.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the touch? If not then please enable it and Hope, it'll sort-out your problem.

I assume that's button in your game screen.

Comment: No i meant the back button on the android phone. The home button on phone works perfectly but the back button is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Just your apps implements for override method for onKeyDown,

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // Here to implements for your code.
        Log.d(TAG, "KEYCODE_BACK");
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Yes i am just overriding onKeyDown function but it works fine on my java android project. It just does not work in my cocos2d-x project.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an update for Cocos2d-x version 3+

This has been answered simply (and works) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049840/back-and-home-buttons-pressed-event-for-android-devices-cocos2d-x-3)

as well as a slightly less complete youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KjKLs_A0gg0)