# Back and Home buttons pressed event for Android devices (cocos2d-x 3)

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have done this to catch `Home` and `Back` buttons press events on android devices:

Overrided `void Layer::onKeyReleased(EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, Event* event)` function like this:

```
void MyLayer::onKeyReleased(EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, Event* event)
{
    if (keyCode == EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_BACKSPACE /*KeyboardEvent::KeyCode::Menu(KEY_BACKSPACE)*/)
    {
         CCLOG("You pressed back button");
         Director::getInstance()->end();
         exit(0);
    } 
    else if (keyCode == EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_HOME)
    {
         CCLOG("You pressed home button");
         // pause the game
    }
}
```

also have called `setKeypadEnabled(true);` in `init` function of `MyLayer`. Backspace button closes the game on windows, but no reaction on Home button. Also on Android nothing happens when I press Home or Back. How to get this working on cocos2d-x 3.1?

Comment: You can't override home button action in android.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For catching Back button you need to use `EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_ESCAPE`. For pausing the game when Home is pressed use void `AppDelegate::applicationDidEnterBackground()`. There is no way to override home button pushed event.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either `EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_BACK` or `EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_ESCAPE` for catching the Android back button event.