# Android Back Button Not working for Cocos2dx

Tags: c#, android, cocos2d-x

i am new in cocos2dx; i have read this answer for back button i could not understand what means this comment;

REF # [Android back button does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697677/android-back-button-does-not-work/13698246#13698246)

@BrandonRomano please pass the main acticyty as an arguments when the Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView instance is been constructed in the main activity. you probably need a variable inside Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView.java to store it, in my case is myActivity.

It is been handled here in the file Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView.java
change it to below, where myActivity is the cocos2dActicity

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using EventListenerKeyboard Class (http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/api-ref/cplusplus/v3x/df/d2a/classcocos2d_1_1_event_listener_keyboard.html)

Example code: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/android-back-button-exits-game/23447/6